# How to run a function on each row in pandas dataframe and have it stop when a condition is met

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a DataFrame, I'm running a function on each row, the function compares values in the row, once a condition is met one of the row elements is added to a dictionary. At this point I want to the function to end, it's not a conventional loop so I can't use `break`.

Should I used a different method of applying the function to each row or is there a way to stop the `apply` method for 'applying' ?

The code

```
test =  # exert from the df I'm using 
    30MA    close
29  0.001311    0.000900
30  0.001313    0.001060
31  0.001294    0.001150
32  0.001290    0.001000
33  0.001293    0.000950
34  0.001305    0.000906
35  0.001310    0.000767
36  0.001318    0.000800
37  0.001325    0.000598
38  0.001331    0.000601

# Create and run buy and hold backtest

# buy and hold is measured by the appriciation from first price that crosses the 30MA to close of the most recent period

buy_and_hold_results = {}
coin = 'BBR'
def buy_and_hold(close, MA, coin):

    if MA < close: 
        entry = close
        exit = coins[coin].loc[len(coins[coin].index)-1].close

        profit = exit / entry

        buy_and_hold_results[coin] = profit

test.apply(lambda x : buy_and_hold(x['close'], x['30MA'], coin), axis=1)

buy_and_hold_results
```

Answer (score 0):

I setup the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
ma = [0.001311, 0.001313, 0.001294, 0.001290, 0.001293, 0.001305, 0.001310, 0.001318, 0.001325, 0.001331]
close = [0.000900, 0.001060, 0.001150, 0.001000, 0.000950, 0.000906, 0.000767, 0.000800, 0.000598, 0.000601]
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(ma, close)), 
               columns =['30MA', 'Close']) 
df
```

This outputs something similar to what you gave:

```
    30MA        Close
0   0.001311    0.000900
1   0.001313    0.001060
2   0.001294    0.001150
3   0.001290    0.001000
4   0.001293    0.000950
5   0.001305    0.000906
6   0.001310    0.000767
7   0.001318    0.000800
8   0.001325    0.000598
9   0.001331    0.000601
```

Your lambda function will in fact apply the same function individually to each row. I would just do this instead:

```
buy_and_hold_results = {}
coin = 'BBR'
for ind, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['30MA'] < row['Close']:
        entry = close
        exit = coins[coin].loc[len(coins[coin].index)-1].close
        profit = exit / entry
        buy_and_hold_results[coin] = profit
        break
        
buy_and_hold_results
```

Note that the above code outputs an empty dictionary. I am not sure what the code is supposed to be doing.